# Return specific text from MySQL using LOCATE and SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql, regex, substring, locate

I want to know how many yards were ran in my NFL SQL database. I use the following query:

```
Select season, description, down, ydsto1st
FROM nflpxp
WHERE 
(
   DESCRIPTION LIKE "%up the middle%" 
   OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP "(left|right) (tackle|guard|end)" 
   OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP " rushe(d|s) for "
)
AND season = 2012 AND off = 'WAS'
GROUP BY id
```

This returns

```
season  description down    ydsto1st
2012    (13:58) (Shotgun) R.Griffin right end to WAS 44 for 12 yards (S.Shanle).    2   10
2012    (11:23) A.Morris right tackle to NO 27 for 3 yards (C.Jordan).  1   10
2012    (10:44) (Shotgun) A.Morris right guard to NO 25 for 2 yards (S.Shanle; B.Bunkley).  2   7
2012    (8:30) (Shotgun) A.Morris right guard to NO 22 for 2 yards (W.Smith).   2   15
```

I want to add a column to my query that pulls out the number of yards run from **"for *nn* yards"**

I tried:

```
SELECT LEFT (description, LOCATE(' yards', description, 2)-1) AS yards FROM nflPxP
```

But it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hail to the Redskins! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work;

```sql
SELECT 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        LEFT(description, 
          GREATEST(LOCATE(' yards (', description),
                   LOCATE(' yard (',  description))-1), ' ', -1)
FROM nflPxP
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0318/1).

While this query works for a row that is fetched by some other search criteria, it's not indexable, so you may want to just add a separate column to store the data if searching the data is required.

Comment: Thanks, this works for everything but runs for 1 yard because "yards" is not plural. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: @NeilG Updated with a slightly more robust version.