# Find a specific sub-string inside MySQL field

Tags: mysql, substring, locate

I have a database with 1 column that has text fields. I need to find and mount a new column with a specific substring. My English isn't good, so I'll try to explain below.

Example of 1 field:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at
>   **XXXX : yyyyy** vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
>   nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option
>   congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim
>   assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis
>   qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores
>   legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus
>   dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est
>   notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram,
>   anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima
>   et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum
>   clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.

I need to find and extract the value of `yyyyy` that comes after `xxxx :`, and the position of the variable inside the text. So far, I've tried this:

```
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(
 RIGHT(description, 
 GREATEST(LOCATE('xxxx :', description),
 LOCATE('xxxx :', description))-1), ' ', -1)
FROM wwwww
```

I know that may be the way to solve it, but I can't make this works right. (I've looked at this already: [Return specific text from MySQL using LOCATE and SUBSTRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911334/return-specific-text-from-mysql-using-locate-and-substring))

PS: The "XXXX :" its always the same... the yyyyy has a variable value

Comment: Do you *HAVE TO* do it in the DB query itself? You can easily do this using regular expressions in almost any programming language, after loading the data from the database.

Comment: No, i don't have to do it in DB... can you point me the direction , using php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description,'XXXX : ',-1),' ',1) from wwwww
```

here's the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bdea2/2/0)

not sure why it isn't working for you maybe try this variation see if this works

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(RIGHT(post_content,LENGTH(post_content) - (LOCATE('XXXX : ',post_content)+6)),' ',1) as var from wp_posts
```

Comment: No success. Got many things but nothing corresponds to the yyyyy (XXXX : yyyyy)

Comment: what does your data really look like? it should work. It works in the sqlFiddle. can you sqlfiddle.com your data?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking, are you wanting the 'yyyyy' or do you want what comes after it? try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/559ad/7/0

Comment: the field i need to filter is post_content

Comment: Looks like your code works correct on  sqlfiddle. But no on mysql query browser here =/

Comment: i updated my answer with another variation using LOCATE and RIGHT try and see if that one works.

Answer (score 0):

To find the first word (or a string) that follows `xxxx :` (possibly with and without spaces around  `:`) in a block of text using PHP and regex:

```php
$subject = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at XXXX : yyyyy vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.";

# Case insensitive match.
$pattern = '/XXXX\s?:\s?(\w+)/i';

# If `XXXX` really has to be all caps, remove the `i` flag, like so:
#$pattern = '/XXXX\s?:\s?(\w+)/';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[1]);

$matched_text = $matches[1][0];
echo $matched_text;

$match_position = $matches[1][1];
echo $match_position;
```